# Firestore return after promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firestore, Cloud Functions and Dialogflow to create a Google Home app. My cloud function should return a calculation based on values in a collection, but I can only return a Promise.

```
// query firestore based on user
var transactions = db.collection('accounts')
               .doc(request.body.result.parameters.accountowner)
               .collection('transactions');
var accountbalance = await transactions.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        var workingbalance = 0
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            workingbalance = workingbalance + doc.data().amount;
        });
        return workingbalance
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting transactions', err);
    });

console.log(accountbalance)
balanceresponse = {
    "speech": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has a balance of $" + accountbalance,
    "displayText": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has an account balance of $" + accountbalance,
    "data": {},
    "contextOut": [],
    "source": "system"
}

response.send(balanceresponse);
```

How can I wait for the promise to return the actual value before calling response.send? I have also tried to put the response.send inside a then, but the function completes and sends headers before the operation completes.

Comment: Just to be clear - you're using await here? Are you using an additional library to add this? (GCF runs Node 6.11, which doesn't have await natively, I thought.)

Comment: Here is a more complete snippet https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7982d7771237f10031102a0281a38b47 (I have removed await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with promises, you need to return values as part of the Promise.then chain. This is usually done by chaining a bunch of `.then()` calls/blocks together. Remember, the `then()` portion will only be called when a Promise resolves.

In your case, it looks like you can just generate `balanceresponse` and call the `response.send()` after you calculate `workingbalance`, inside the same block of code. The call to `response.send()` doesn't need to be at the end of the function. So you might have that block look something like:

```
.then(snapshot => {
    var workingbalance = 0
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        workingbalance = workingbalance + doc.data().amount;
    });

    balanceresponse = {
      "speech": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has a balance of $" + workingbalance,
      "displayText": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has an account balance of $" + workingbalance,
      "data": {},
      "contextOut": [],
      "source": "system"
    }

    response.send(balanceresponse); 
})
```

If, for some reason, you wanted to separate the calculation and compute the `balanceresponse` in a different block, you could do so. I don't necessarily recommend this, but it has some merits (for example, you could put multiple catch blocks after each part, which I've shown here):

```
// query firestore based on user
var transactions = db.collection('accounts')
               .doc(request.body.result.parameters.accountowner)
               .collection('transactions');
await transactions.get()

    .then(snapshot => {
        var workingbalance = 0
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            workingbalance = workingbalance + doc.data().amount;
        });
        return workingbalance
    })

    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting transactions', err);
    });

    .then( accountbalance => {
        balanceresponse = {
            "speech": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has a balance of $" + accountbalance,
            "displayText": request.body.result.parameters.accountowner + " has an account balance of $" + accountbalance,
            "data": {},
            "contextOut": [],
            "source": "system"
        }
        response.send(balanceresponse);    
    })

    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error sending response', err);
    });
```

Comment: I had tried this previously (and again just now). The problem is that `response.send` needs to be called synchronously. When I leave it in the `.then`, it does try to send a response, but the function has already exited so the requester (Dialogflow in this case) never gets a response.

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere else. {: `response.send()` doesn't need to be called synchronously - I do this exact scenario (tho using the real time database rather than firestore) for Actions on Google as well. Assuming "response" is one of the parameters passed to your cloud function. How is this function being called? Is it possible for you to post a minimal, complete, code sample of what you're seeing?

Comment: I added a link to a gist that includes the function export

Comment: In the gist you posted, line 13 returns from the function before `response.send()` is called. Note that I had removed this from my first example block above. (I also fixed a variable name usage in that example.)

Comment: You're right, and with that change it is now working.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: hi. I am facing the exact same issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576932/unhandled-rejection-headers-cant-be-set-after-they-are-sent?s=3|42.3765 . Now i understand that the Unhandled rejection is due to the response.send(). As the headers are set before they are sent. I tried this solution but I am quite not getting how to go about it. Can you please help me?